# Larping space and recruiting help

Tags: larp

I am setting up a LARP meet up with a friend.We have most of our supplies like weapons and costumes,but our main problem is finding a safe place to larp.The only place that resembles a woodland area is the back of my apartment and a nature park around the corner,which rejected my plea.We also need more people to participate.It is only 2 people right now and we would really like to have more people so it can be more fun.How do I find more people in my area that may be interested in our new group and how do I find a new place thats safe and enjoyable?

Comment: Finding new people is a separate issue to how to find a location that's safe and enjoyable. Please ask them in separate questions, so we can go fully into depth on each one appropriately. At the moment, since this question is almost entirely about _where_ to LARP and the challenges you're facing in finding a place, I suggest you edit this one to just focus on that.

Comment: You have two questions here. I have a good answer to the second one (where to find a good place to larp) and will post it if you open a new question.

Answer (score 3):

## [MeetUp](http://www.meetup.com/) is Your Friend

You can try meetup, which helps people find like-minded people for various activities, including LARPing.

## Your Local Game Store is Also Your Friend

My local comic book shop also sells LARP equipment, and they can usually point people to a group. I would suggest trying that place out.